# PlayFramework handling of special characters in HTTP header

Tags: java, unicode, playframework

When I send special characters like `â` through HTTP header value, I get a different unicode character `request().getHeader()`.

I know it's not recommended to send special characters over HTTP headers but this is a requirement for me and first I thought it's because of JVM encoding not being set to UTF-8. But even after setting I get the same issue.

I have seen someone asked a similar question:

[Play Framework Unicode symbols in HTTP Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648260/play-framework-unicode-symbols-in-http-header)

But hasn't got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about Play or Java, it's about HTTP standard. You need to encode that characters, there is no guaranteed way to send non-ASCII character in HTTP header.

[How to send non-English unicode string using HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423223/how-to-send-non-english-unicode-string-using-http-header)

[Illegal characters in HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028068/illegal-characters-in-http-headers)

[Sending non-ASCII text in Http POST header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251824/sending-non-ascii-text-in-http-post-header)

[What character encoding should I use for a HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400678/what-character-encoding-should-i-use-for-a-http-header)

Even for RFC5987:

[handling filename* parameters with spaces via RFC 5987 results in '+' in filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302361/handling-filename-parameters-with-spaces-via-rfc-5987-results-in-in-filenam)

Comment: Yes i understand the HTTP standard. But as i found out Jetty server respects the file.encoding setting, even for the HTTP headers. But Netty server strictly adhere to the HTTP standard. I think only way forward for me is to encode it with base64.